# SQL Insert Statement Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have written a sample to insert txt file to MySql DB but i am getting an error as unknown column _Fname

My code:

```
string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(FName,FData) values (_FName, _FData)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_FName", filename);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_FData", bytes);
```

Even this to the same error:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("_FName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
cmd.Parameters.Add("_FData", MySqlDbType.LongText).Value = bytes;
```

Comment: I think you need to add @ before each string you want to use as a parameter name.

Comment: Not a MySql person, but shouldn't the parameter inside values have an @ prefixed? So it looks like @_FName,@_FData ?

Comment: Please put in the exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the _FName is not being interpretted as a token/parameter by the command.

Try using @_FName instead ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(FName,FData) values (?, ?)";
```

Note that If you're using a .NET native provider for MySQL then you might (just might)
be able to get away with named parameters. However, if you're using the
OleDB interface, parameters are positional (not named) and must be marked
with a "?" character.

Answer (score 1):

instead of "_FName" use "@_FName" or simply "?". This way, the parameters get properly substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to add an @ before parameter names so that the mysql can understand the difference between a value, column name , and a literal.

Comment: Sorry by "value" I mean the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do the trick:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_FName", filename);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_FData", bytes);
```

See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) for more information and even examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your new MySqlCommand() is missing a connection, intended? Also, you should write parameters as @Name not _Name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(FName,FData) values (@FName, @FData)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", filename);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FData", bytes);
```